# Why doesn’t work when regex entering 1 letter after the optional character?

Tags: regex, string

I've custom regex pattern for check correct username on url:

```
^[@](?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?$
```

This pattern work when I write usernames:

```
@username
@username_16
@username16
```

But not work when I write:

```
@u
```

**First part of question:**
How to rewrite this pattern for work in `@u`?

**Second part of question:**
How control characters limit or length after `@` symbol?

Comment: Should `@` pass? Your regex allows this. I'd suggest `^@[a-z](?:[a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?$` if not.

Comment: Yes, symbol `@` need on start username @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: I mean, do you really want to match a `@` string with no letters or numbers or  `_` after it?

Comment: Only `@` no match. Correct username only with `@` and need a-z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[a-z]` and `[a-z0-9]` are obligatory patterns inside the optional group, hence if there is something after `@`, there must be two chars at least.

Besides, your regex also matches a string that equals `@`.

To fix all these issues you may use

```
^@[a-z](?:[a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5PhCku/1).

Now, to restrict the length of a string after `@` symbol, you may insert a `(?=.{x,m}$)` positive lookahead right after `@`. Say, to only match 3 or 4 chars after `@`, use:

```
^@(?=[a-z0-9_]{3,4}$)[a-z](?:[a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?$
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or, since the consuming pattern will validate the rest

```
^@(?=.{3,4}$)[a-z](?:[a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?$
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X6Rs41/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{3,4}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires any 3 or 4 chars other than line break chars up to the end of the string immediately to the right of the current location (i.e. from the string start here)
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?:[a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `[a-z0-9_]*` - 0+ lowercase ASCII letters, digits or `_`
  - `[a-z0-9]` - a lowercase ASCII letter or  digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This pattern work but how to control characters length after `@` symbol?

Comment: @Otabek Please provide an example. A hint: you may use lookaheads like `^(?=[a-z0-9_]{6,18}$)@[a-z](?:[a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?$` to control overall string length, to match strings of 6 to 18 chars in length.

Comment: For example I have custom username `@us_1`. Here I have 4 charakters [us_1] after `@` symbol and how to limit max and min characters length only after `@`. For example after `@` symbol characters min length = 3 and max length = 4. In this case this usernames will be correct: @us_1, @us2. This is incorrect usernames: @use_2 and @user_stack_22. @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @Otabek Ok, `^@[a-z](?:[a-z0-9_]{1,2}[a-z0-9])?$` will match a string starting with `@`, then has 3 or 4 chars. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/X6Rs41/1). That is, subtract 2 from the threshold values you have to obtain the values for the limiting quantifier. However, a more generic solution is `^@[a-z](?=[a-z0-9_]{2,3}$)(?:[a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?$`

Comment: @Otabek That part of the question has no attempt from you. I do not know what your code looks like, what programming language you are using. Show it.

Comment: Please add to your answer this regex to `^@[a-z](?=[a-z0-9_]{2,4}$)(?:[a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?$ ` with details and I will accerpt it @Wiktor Stribiżew